# Trying to retrieve data from database then pass to html in Rails's view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to Rails and JQuery/Ajax, and I am trying send some of database information to my view htmls through JQuery's Ajax. In the process of learning the style of it, I figured that

```
                    var json = {....};

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '...',
                        data: json,
                        success: function (data){
                            //do such with data when successful
                        },
                        error: function (data){
                            //do such with data when failed
                        }
                    });
```

I am trying to let data return with an array of strings, so I could put the database data in the JQuery autocomplete tags. What do I need to do in the controller?For example, if I want user.name from all users in users model.

Comment: Have you tried asking Google for help? Try searching for "ruby on rails jquery tutorial".

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did, but couldn't find anything similar to this.

Comment: Try a search like [this one](https://google.com/?q=rails+ajax+action)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't being clear enough, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just trying to answer this question because when I started out with Rails no one helped me. Everyone just said google it.
All the examples where good but I wasn't able to figure the stuff out and connect the important things.

Your Rails app is most likely a RESTful application.
That means let's say you got a **products_controller.rb**.

Then you could access them like so:

```
# all products
/products

# all products as json
/products.json

# the first product
/products/1

# call the edit page for the first product
/products/1/edit

# get the first product in json format
# we will need this in a moment
/products/1.json
```

If you type in your commandline:

```
rake routes
```

You will see all the corresponding actions.
Usually you got something like that in your **routes.rb**:

```
resources :products
```

Now let's try retrieving the first product as json:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/products/1.json',                              
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                // callback
        },
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          alert(data);
          // from here on you could also get the product id 
          // or whatever you need
          $('#someDiv').html(data); // insert the retrieved data
          // into a html element.
           console.log(data.name); // output the name
           console.log(data.price); // output the price
        },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // error callback
            }
        });
    });
```

You obv. use JQuery therefore you can add the [Jquery each method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) into your success callback.

There are other/easier/faster ways to accomplish this but this would suite your given example.

Now let's try to iterate over all products.
Notice that the url changed because now we want every available product.

```
 $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/products.json',                              
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                // callback
        },
          success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          alert(data);
          // from here on you could also get the product id 
          // or whatever you need
         $.each(data, function(k)  { 
             console.log(data[k].name); // name of products
          });
        },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // error callback
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to make a loop to get all the products? Is there way to manipulate json in controller, so it returns for example product.name of all product names in a string?

Comment: As described you can use the JQuery each loop to iterate over the values. then you can access the stuff like product.id, product.name etc...

Comment: @lostdong12 Check out my example I've added how to access the attributes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i got the stuff i need from using the code. One question, what is .json in products.json?

Comment: If you enter /products.any_format Rails will generate this view for you. You can also manually enter in your Browser /products.xml and If you got a respond_to block for xml you will get xml.

If you type in /products.html you will get the default view.
If you type in /products.json you will get the json view.

Try it manually in your browser.